# Submit value from form to method without variable in the BackingBean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a simple form where a user enters his username and password, in the bean it's checked if the values are correct.

**.xhtml**

```xhtml
<p:outputLabel value="Username:" />
<p:inputText value="#{fooBean.username}" />

<p:outputLabel value="Passwort:" />
<p:password value="#{fooBean.password}" />

<p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{fooBean.check()}" />
```

**fooBean**

```
public void check() {
    if(username == "name" && password == "pass") {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Now my question is if there is a way to submit the values of the inputTexts to a function `check(String username, String password)`, without having to declare the fields in the bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply:

```xhtml
<p:outputLabel value="Passwort:" />
<p:password value="#{password}" />

<p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{fooBean.check(username, password)}" />
```

will work, but maybe enlarging scope is better:

```xhtml
<p:outputLabel value="Passwort:" />
<p:password value="#{viewScope.password}" />

<p:commandButton value="Login" 
    action="#{fooBean.check(viewScope.username, viewScope.password)}" />
```

Comment: Does this have any disadvantages in comparaison with the usual way ?

Comment: main disadvantages are that you need a bean/event listener for variable initialization and i think that an intense use of this technique can lead to hard maintenable code: with templates and inclusion it is easy to put in the same scope two different objects with the same name. finding this kind of bugs can be a real pain.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti, if you could provide me with one further advice, how can I reset the values after the form is submitted? This form is within a dialog and after submitting it only the password inputText is resetted.

Comment: @Rosty resetting non-processed inputs is a JSF design leak, IMO. take a look at [OmniFaces ResetInputAjaxActionListener](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/ResetInputAjaxActionListener)